# Multistep form field with jquery toggle fieldsets

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a multistep form and would like to utilize jquery and bootstrap to achieve the following functionality:

- When user clicks on the legend, its corresponding fieldset expands
- When user clicks 'next' button, that fieldset closes and the next one opens
- When user clicks 'previous' button, that fieldset closes and previous one opens

All of these behaviors should toggle the glyphicon-plus-sign glyphicon-minus-sign icon.  My jquery code is below the html.

HTML:

```
 <fieldset>
 <legend class="bg-info"><span class="badge progress-bar-info" style="font-size:18px;">1</span> Registration Details <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus-sign pull-right" aria-hidden="true"></span></legend>
    <div class="form_container">Content</div>
    <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />
 </fieldset>

<fieldset>
        <legend class="bg-info"><span class="badge progress-bar-info" style="font-size:18px;">2</span> Age Groups and Divisions <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign pull-right" aria-hidden="true"></span></legend>
    <div class="form_container" style="display:none;">Content</div>
    <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous" />
    <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />
</fieldset>
```

JQUERY:

```
$(function(){
    // Set cursor to pointer and add click function
    $("legend").css("cursor","pointer").click(function(){
        var legend = $(this);
       $(this).siblings().slideToggle("slow", function() { legend.children(".glyphicon").toggleClass("glyphicon-plus-sign glyphicon-minus-sign"); } );
    });
});

$(".next").click(function(){

    current_fs = $(this).parent();
    next_fs = $(this).parent().next("fieldset");

    $(this).closest(".form_container").slideToggle("slow", function() { current_fs.closest("legend span.glyphicon").toggleClass("glyphicon-plus-sign glyphicon-minus-sign"); } );
    $(this).next(".form_container").slideToggle("slow", function() { $(this).parent().children("legend.glyphicon").toggleClass("glyphicon-plus-sign glyphicon-minus-sign"); } );

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using bootstrap's built in `accordion` and adding a little bit of javascript to control the icons:

Here's a bootply example: http://www.bootply.com/WSrtmlu4W3

HTML

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
          Registration Details <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span>
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
      <div class="panel-body">
        <p>blah blah blah</p>
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseTwo" class="btn btn-default">Next</a> 
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
          Age Groups and Divisions <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
      <div class="panel-body">
        <p>blah blah blah</p>
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne" class="btn btn-default">Previous</a>
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseThree" class="btn btn-default">Next</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$('.collapse').on('shown.bs.collapse', function(){
    $(this).parent().find(".glyphicon-plus").removeClass("glyphicon-plus").addClass("glyphicon-minus");
});

$('.collapse').on('hidden.bs.collapse', function(){
    $(this).parent().find(".glyphicon-minus").removeClass("glyphicon-minus").addClass("glyphicon-plus");
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this was a great start and I will accept it as the answer.  Can you also provide the jquery to have the entire panel head clickable to expand/collapse and not just the link? -- Nevermind, all I had to do was move the data-toggle, data-parent, and href up to the panel-heading